# RegEx for matching Cyrillic, numbers, space and some special chars (- \ , :

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, xregexp

I do have the following RegExp in the current web application.

```
function myCyrillicDigitsAndSpaceValidator(text){
    return XRegExp("^[\\p{Cyrillic}0-9]+").test(text);
}
```

As you can see I use XRegExp javasciprt library. Currently, this regxep checks if its cyrillic+has space+has numbers. I want to extend it and to check:

> It's Cyrillic
>
> It does have space
>
> It does have numbers
>
> It does have special chars

`XregxExp version is 2.0.0 if it does matter`

Correct examples:

```
1 Май

-

Май 25\5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add any special chars and other chars that you wish to the list you already have, such as:

```
^[\\p{Cyrillic}0-9#$%^&\-\s\\]+$
```

or

```
([\\p{Cyrillic}0-9\\s\-#$%^&\\]+)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/UNRe2J/1)

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tKfcfg/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

Comment: It's good practice to either move the `-` after `\s` to the end or beginning or to escape it. Then there is definitely no chance of it being interpreted as a range.

Comment: This doesn't seem correct, because e.g. it would match a purely numeric text, or a text which only had e.g. Cyrillic characters and nothing else.

Comment: it gives error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u0527\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA697\uA69F0-9#$%^&-s\]+/: Unterminated character class`

Comment: For some reason it's working fine in validator demo but not in actual app. This is the new error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[p{Cyrillic}0-9s-#$%^&\]+/: Range out of order in character class`

Comment: But in my OP it's working just fine without any escaping... why should I escape meta chars now?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using positive lookaheads for this purpose.  Consider the following regex pattern:

```
^(?=.* )
 (?=.*\d)
 (?=.*[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/])
 (?=.*[\p{Cyrillic}])
 [ \d-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/\p{Cyrillic}]+
$
```

This asserts, in order, that a space, number, symbol, and Cyrillic character all occur in the input.  Then, it matches one or more of these four classes of characters.

Your updated code:

```
function myCyrillicDigitsAndSpaceValidator(text){
    return XRegExp("^(?=.* )(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,.\\/])(?=.*[\\p{Cyrillic}])[ \\d-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,.\\/\\p{Cyrillic}]+$").test(text);
}
```

Comment: @Daler I updated my answer, and it seems to at least parse correctly now ([see here](https://rextester.com/XFJMT57244)).  Try it again please.

Comment: tests doesnt pass with this regexp. The result is always false for tested strings

Comment: I had the same result, but I was using `RegExp`.  Not sure if perhaps you have some encoding problem on your end.

Comment: my original expression in my post does work just fine. It doesn't have any encoding problems.. Must be something wrong with expression itself

Comment: Minus the Cyrillic issue, my `XRegExp` code is basically working for me here locally.  I will tell that lookaheads are the way to go in this case, most likely.

Comment: it still doesnt work.. acts the same way as it was before not validating anyhting

Comment: I can't debug any more than I already have.  If you remove the restrictions on Cyrillic, the pattern works.  Pick this up and go from here.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But the `Cyrillic` is the main part. I can't remove it. Otherwise I would simply remove any sort of validation on that field..